# Restrict access to vertex classes in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'm looking at OrientDB as a possible data base. I'm quite intrigued by the ability to create vertex classes from which to instantiate vertices. My question is related to the access to these classes:

Is it possible to restrict access to classes (i.e. being able to create a vertex based on a class) per user/role?

Example:

User A creates a vertex class

```
CREATE CLASS ClassA EXTENDS V
```

User A should obviously be able to create vertices of class `ClassA`. But they should be the only one to do so, possibly even be the only ones who can see that class `ClassA` exists. So User B should not be able to do

```
CREATE VERTEX ClassA
```

From what I've read I have the feeling that this might be possible using clusters, but from the documentation I could not find out how that would be done.

Comment: Hi. Have you seen this ? http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Grant.html

Comment: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Database-Security.html

Comment: Hi, have you seen these? https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Multi-Tenant.html https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Partitioned-Graphs.htmlThx

Comment: Hi, yes, I've read all of these, but I don't think they answer this question. I understand how to restrict access to vertices, but what about classes? Classes do not live in the graph, but in the schema. It seems restricting users from using a specific class to create instances is not possible.

Comment: as said here http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Grant.html you can set permissions on `database.class.<class>`